# I need to understand something about Ubuntu's default backgrounds and resolution

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, resolution

So I have an old laptop with a resolution 1024x768 and if I want to use a bigger photo for background it always crops itself or I have to use in scale mode which is not a thing I like to do. But I noticed that the default background photos of Ubuntu are around 2500x1600 in resolution but they all fit perfectly on my screen. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The ratio of 2500x1600 is 1.5625 and your 1024x768 ratio is 1.1/3 or 1.33333. A typical desktop at 1366x768 is 1.77865 and 1200x740 is 1.62162.

The desktop backgrounds only appear to fit perfectly but they actually are either using the scale or the zoom setting. My best guess is that the zoom setting is the one used. You can see in this screenshot of my desktop using 1024x768 with a comparison of the photo in the foreground how the sides of the photo are cropped off and not seen when used as wallpaper. This background is included with the ubuntustudio package.

The actual photo files are contained in the folder **/usr/share/backgrounds** you can take a look at the pictures here and see how the default background photos compare to the display on your desktop.

[image]